# Update rows based on previous select statement

Tags: mysql, arrays, select, sql-update

I need to do as many updates as needed based on a select.

Let's say I have two tables "Groups" and "Members".

"Groups"

```
GroupName  GroupID
Genius     1
Clever     2
Normal     3
Stupid     4
Donkey     5
```

"Members"

```
MemberName     GroupID
John           1
Peter          3
Mary           1
Ashley         2
Robin          1
Louis          5
Bill           4
Paul           5
```

I want to change members from a GroupID to another.

I.e: Members from "Clever" to "Donkey".

```
select MemberName from Members where GroupID='1';
while($arr = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
$name = $arr['MemberName'];
}
```

Then I will update all the selected members into the new group:

```
$sql .= update Members set GroupID='5' where MemberName='$name';
```

I know I have to put all names into an array in order to update each one separately, but I'm a bit confused also in the correct update syntax.

Comment: how will you select to which group you want to move member in? I mean, you want to push Member X from group A to group B. Right. Thats what you want to do. You will click on Member X and that will give you group A. But my question is that how will you decide to which group the system should move the member too. Hope i am clear to explain my doubt

Comment: Bhavik, it will be completely arbitrary. I was looking so deeply into this matter that I forgot how easy it was (as Mark B stated). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply

```
UPDATE Members SET GroupID=5 WHERE GroupID=1
```

?

Your method would only be required if you had to do some ugly/complicated processing that couldn't be done in SQL (or would be even uglier in SQL).

Comment: Wait...it seems I'm complicating it indeed... I was thinking too much about it and forgot how simple it was...

Comment: deleting questions counts as a strike against you - deletion is for spam/out-of-control discussions.

Comment: I know...but shouldn't we keep the community clean? this is a common-asked question, repeated...Anyway, there is no problem me for at all to keep it. Thank you again Marc.

Comment: "bad" stuff will just naturally sink to the bottom, and good ones will float upwards as they get upvoted. no worries.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this is by following:

```
SELECT  @DonkeyGrpID:=GroupID 
FROM Groups 
WHERE GroupName = 'Donkey';

UPDATE Members M, Groups G  
SET M.GroupID = @DonkeyGrpID
WHERE M.GroupID = G.GroupID AND G.GroupName = 'Clever' ;
```